# TSQL to ensure the rows arrive in order of date, when rows are fetched using a cursor?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm wondering if its possible to put a constraint on the "date" column in a table, so that when data is fetched using a cursor, it always arrives with the dates in order?

Comment: Is it not sufficient just to have an `ORDER BY` on the cursor declaration?

Comment: also - a cursor? really? if it is a *reader*, then fine - but an actual *cursor* is generally quite an overhead, and to be avoided

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to guarantee the ordering of data returned by a query is to use an ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply query the rows in order by date?

Answer (score 3):

```
declare Cur cursor for select Col1 from YourTable order by DateCol
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ORDER BY. You should also consider using a set-based approach without a cursor where possible. Cursors generally speaking are more complex to develop and maintain and frequently perform poorly compared to a set-based solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set a ascending clustered index on the date column? This means that the rows can only be returned in one order, and selects are a lot faster. This is excellent for time series.